# How to solve all solutions for Ax=B on GF(2) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Given A and B, solving for x on GF(2) should give 2 solutions. Example:

```
A = [
1 0 0 0 1;
0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 1 0 0;
0 0 0 1 1;  ]
```

B(transpose) = [0 0 0 0 0]

so Ax = B yields x = [0 0 0 0 0] and x = [1 0 0 1 1]
you can see as

```
x1 + x5 = 0
x2 = 0
x3 = 0
x4 + x5 = 0
```

clearly, x1 and x5 can be 0 or 1, and x4 can be 0 or 1

I should add: I tried using

```
gflineq(A, B, 2);
```

But only got one solution

Comment: to solve for all the solutions is hard. Check [this](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2019/07/08/the-worlds-simplest-impossible-problem/) text showing different approaches to solve a system of equations whose number of equations is different than the number of variables.

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got a system of boolean equations and are looking for all solutions.  If the number of equations and variables is small, the simplest thing is probably to just enumerate all the possible solutions (2^5 = 32 cases in your little example), check each in turn, and keep the ones that satisfy the system.

If you're looking for a general representation that is more practical in many cases (though obviously still exponential in general), I'd suggest something like BDDs ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram ) There are various well-developed packages available for manipulating them.  I'm not sure about interfacing them to Matlab though.